# primefaces paint cell red on validator exception

Tags: primefaces, datatable, validation

I have a datatable with editable cells. When a validation error occurs, the cell border gets painted red. I want to the whole cell to be painted red. Is there any way to do this? This is the column code:

```xhtml
<p:column width="15%" id="ParameterColumn"  headerText="Parameter" sortBy="#{p.name}"
    filterBy="#{p.name}" filterMatchMode="contains">
    <p:cellEditor id="Parameter">
        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText id="param_name" value="#{p.name}" />
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
            <p:inputText id="nameInput" value="#{p.name}" style="width:99%"
                validator="#{p.validateParamName}">
            </p:inputText>
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```